# Point of Origin issue

Tags: modeling

In this stock Patron bottle, it seems to have different origins for the label as to where the label is placed (and for the bottle) and I can't seem to reset the origin to geometry.  When I move the label (or bottle) this black dashed line stays connected to the the point on the top in my diagram. What am I not getting? Plus when i selected the already joined objects of the bottle, cork and ribbon and try to join them to the label --the label disappears!

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you share the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can post a .blend I'll be able to tell you in more detail how you have arranged your object hierarchy. But first of all, note the "plus" icons to the left of your objects:

[image: Object hierarchy]

Click this to expand it and see the children objects of that parent object.

Also note that the black dotted lines in your 3D Viewport show you the relationship between parent and child objects.

You can redefine the position of an object's Origin Point by using the Set Origin button:

[image: Set Origin button]

The one you will probably use most frequently is Origin to 3D Cursor. With this operation, the current position of your 3D Cursor will become the position of your selected object(s)' Origin Point(s).

As for the label disappearing when joined to another object - this may be due to a difference in modifiers. If for example, your ribbon is only visible and raised above the surface of your bottle because it uses a Solidify Modifier, and suddenly you Join it to the Patron bottle object which doesn't have that modifier (let's assume), then of course the influence of that modifier is gone, and instead it comes under the influence of whatever modifiers might be on the Patron bottle object.

### Update:

So, after taking a glance at your .blend, as expected, the label is one of those objects that has its origin off... somewhere over there.

[image: Object names made visible]

I made the names visible, so hopefully this will help you figure out what is what. By the way, here's how to do that:

[image: Make names visible]

Here's the .blend with names made visible and the hierarchy expanded.

[image]

To summarize the problem, It looks like you joined some objects you didn't mean to, and parented some objects in ways you didn't mean to.

You can select parts of your mesh within Edit Mode and press <kbd>P</kbd> to seParate them back out into their own objects.

To un-parent an object you can select it and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

So see if an object has a parent, and check the parent's name, besides looking in the Outliner you can also look here:

[image: Check an object's parent in Relations]

Good luck! With the info I explained above it shouldn't be too difficult to reorganize, and I'm sure you will gain some useful knowledge in the process.

Comment: Added blend file. (sorry it's 30+ mb) It does not appear to do anything when I try to set the origin.. which was something I already tried. I can't make the origin of the child align with that of the object. (either label or bottle)

Comment: Alt + P and "clear and keep transformation" worked!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! Would you mind marking my answer as accepted if it helped you?